# Angle transformation under Lorentz transformation

Tags: special-relativity, coordinate-systems, inertial-frames

The **angle transformation** under Lorentz transformation:

$$
\cos\theta = \frac{\cos\theta' + \beta}{1 + \beta\cos\theta},\quad \sin\theta = \frac{\sin\theta'}{\gamma^2(1 + \beta\cos\theta')}
$$

is normally derived from the **velocity transformation**:

$$
u_\parallel = \frac{u_\parallel' + v}{1+(v/c^2)u_\parallel'},\quad u_\perp = \frac{u_\perp/\gamma}{1+(v/c^2)u_\parallel'}
$$

and then

$$
\tan\theta = \frac{u_\perp}{u_\parallel} = \frac{u_\perp'/\gamma}{u_\parallel' + v} = \frac{u'\sin\theta'}{\gamma(u'\cos\theta + v)}
$$

letting $u' = c$ and get:

$$
\tan\theta = \frac{\sin\theta'}{\gamma(\cos\theta'+\beta)}
$$

---

I am wondering why we don't start with the **length transformation**:

$$
x = \gamma(x'+\beta ct'),\quad y = y'
$$

and:

$$
\tan\theta = \frac{y}{x} = \frac{y'}{\gamma(x'+\beta ct')}
$$

**which leads to an annoying $ct'$ here**

---

**Can someone tell me why we must use velocity transformation and not length transformation to get the angle transformation?**

Comment: Why not start with "time transformation"?  Velocity is not any kind of "associated quantity" with length.

Comment: time transformation is associated with length

Answer (score 1):

I think, since you are only considering 2D (as oposed to 3D), i.e. a component of the velocity that is perpendicular to the Lorentz transformation and another that is parallel with it, you are allowed to say that
$$x'=r'\cos\theta'\\y'=r'\sin\theta'$$
for some distance $r'$. The latter distance, then, is going to be the distance that satisfies $ct'=r'$, and therefore you will have the Eq. in your original post
$$\tan\theta=\frac{\sin\theta'}{\gamma(\cos\theta'+\beta)}$$